# Customizing tabbar-buffer-groups-function has no effect

Tags: emacs, tabs

I want to setup a tab scheme like this:

- All IRC-related buffers in "irc" tab group
- All dired buffers and Emacs-internal buffers like `*scratch*`/`*messages*` in "emacs"
- All other buffers in "user"

I've configured my [.emacs](https://github.com/mcandre/dotfiles/blob/master/.emacs#L139) for this, but my custom tabbar-buffer-groups-function has no effect. Tab groups are behaving like defaults, like I didn't write this function. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, `(setq ... (lambda ...` should be `(defun tabbar-buffer-groups () ...`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```lisp
(defun tabbar-buffer-groups-common ()
  "Returns the list of group names the current buffer belongs to."
  (list
   (cond
    ((string-equal "*" (substring (buffer-name) 0 1))
     "emacs"
     )
    ((string-match "irc" (format "%s" major-mode))
     "irc"
     )
    (t
     "user")
     )))
```

(I've never used irc in emacs, so I'm not sure about it).